# How do I create a "tabbed" look in a single piece of HTML that I can display in a webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, html

I have a process that is going to create a piece of STATIC html that is associated with a record. Another screen will that load a bunch of records that have this piece of associated static html. While the records are shown in a multi-grid layout, the currently selected record's associated html is displayed in a web browser control. The data is growing too large for the screen real estate and I'd like to show the data in some logical groups - perhaps tabs - perhaps someother way inside the web browser control. Is there a way to do this in HTML? Remember a seperate process has preformed the associated html and all I do in this screen is load it into the web browser contro.

Sample static HTML that I'm talking about:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}</STYLE>
    </head>
    <table border="0"><caption>We confirm the following FX Transaction</caption>
    <tr><td>Customer:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">PHONE CUST</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Instrument Id:</td><td  align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">FX</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Trade Date:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">09/28/2010</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Value Date:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">09/30/2010</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Currency Pair:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">EUR/USD</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Direction:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">SELL</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ccy Id 1:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">EUR</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ccy 1 Amount:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">-75,000.00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Trade Price:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">1.2698</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ccy Id 2:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">USD</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ccy 2 Amount:</td><td align = RIGHT bgcolor = "#00FFFF">95,235.00</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a specimen/demo html you can post so we know what we're working with?

Comment: Editing post to contain sample of what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly how to help you, based on the available info.  However, you should be able to do it by adding some javascript to the "static HTML".

This javascript could use JQuery and one of the tab-related plugins to modify the DOM after the page loads.  If that isn't possible, you can still take a look at them for ideas.

Comment: Thanks - and I saw this answer when I did a search. I was wondering if there was a simpler approach (no javascript) - doesn't have to be tab based, just some way to cycle through a couple of windows worth of data

Comment: If you want behavior, you need one of three things: Javascript, an predefined HTML behavior, or CSS.  I believe Javascript is your only real choice, unless you use something simple like scrolling or a less-simple hide/show CSS setup (based on mouse hovering) might work.